# For each node in tree, add underscores to each node so that all children are covered

Tags: python, recursion, tree, tuples

I'm trying to write a function which takes a tree, and return a new tree where each node covers all of its children and has brackets around it.

This is my current function. I have found it difficult to keep track of what's going on due to the recursion and even after sometime spent playing around, pinpointing the problem/s is still challenging.

```
 def covered_tree(node):
  parent, children = node
  new_node = None
  for childs in children:
    cover_len = 0
    for each_child in childs:
      covered_tree(childs)
      cover_len += len(each_child)
    cover_len -= len(parent)-2
    parent = '['+parent+'_'*cover_len+']'
    new_node = (parent, children)
  return new_node
```

For input,

```
("hello", (("a", ()), ("b", (("cde", ()), ("fg", ())))))
```

expected output,

```
('[hello_____]', (('[a]', ()), ('[b______]', (('[cde]', ()), ('[fg]', ())))))
```

b is followed by 6 underscores since len('[cde]'+'[fg]')-2-len('a') is 6, the minus two is for the outside brackets.

Comment: why should `hello` be followed by 5 underscores  and `b` - 6 ? Clarify your logic

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I have edited the question with clarification. The same logic applies to hello, len('[a]'+'[b______]')-2-len('hello') equals 5. Hope that is better

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
def cover_tree(d):
   c = tuple(map(cover_tree, d[1]))
   return ('['+d[0]+']'+('_'*(sum(len(j) for j, _ in c) - 2 - len(d[0]))), c)

tree = ("hello", (("a", ()), ("b", (("cde", ()), ("fg", ())))))
print(cover_tree(tree))
```

Output:

```
('[hello]_____', (('[a]', ()), ('[b]______', (('[cde]', ()), ('[fg]', ())))))
```